# History.js implementation

Tags: history.js

I'm having trouble implementing history.js

I have a single page website that uses a jquery slider (royal slider) to slide full page divs that act as pages. The slider is operated using custom links. What I would like to do is have each link manipulate the browser history in order to 1. change the page URL. and 2. push states to the browser that are refreshable and can be navigated to and from via the browser's forward and back buttons.

What I'm not sure about is whether any pushstate will save the sliders current slide?
It's not essential if not, as the change in URL is the main thing.

Each link is controlled via a javascript click function that looks like this...

```
var workclick = document.getElementById('worklink');
workclick.onclick = function () {
        thefooter.style.opacity = "1";
        thefooter.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=100)';
        thefootdivide.style.opacity = "1";
        thefootdivide.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=100)';  
        $(".royalSlider").royalSlider('goTo', 1);

    }
```

Can somebody help me with what I need to add to my page to get history.js to work with what I have here?

Thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on History.js, but my understanding is that once it's installed, each time a slider value is changed you could call replaceState() with url parameters that reflect their values something like :

```
History.replaceState( null, 'My Title', '?slider1=' + $('#slider1').value );
```

And then, when your page loads have it read these request parameter values and (if present) set the sliders accordingly.
Again I'm not sure this is exactly what you need but I'm pretty sure it's on the right track.